# R is unexpectedly transforming field from CSV file to NA

Tags: r

I'm trying to parse CSV file in R. Here is the first line of CSV file with separator `~`. Please note `i` literal at second field position.

```
2015-10-29 18:49:42~i~186.37.108.44~Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.1.2; GT-S6810E Build/JZO54K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.94 Mobile Safari/537.36~ea01627ed45116787d3b1c0224a44d77~?~CL~1443~219~729~335~3155~9214~5
```

Here is how I'm trying to parse it:

```
> parsed <- read.csv('i.csv', header=F, sep='~')
> parsed$V2
  [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 [37] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 [73] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[109] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[145] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[181] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[217] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[253] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[289] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
> table(count.fields('i.csv', sep='~'))

 14 
310
```

Why this happens? Why field#2 is NA istead of `i`? All other fields are ok, field#1 and field#3 do not contains `i` literal. All other fields are also OK.

```
> df$V1[1]
[1] 2015-10-29 18:38:04
257 Levels: 2015-10-29 18:38:04 2015-10-29 18:38:07 2015-10-29 18:38:12 ... 2015-10-29 18:51:46
> df$V3[1]
[1] 24.237.158.3
270 Levels: 1.144.97.1 1.187.195.221 1.187.204.84 1.39.12.184 1.39.13.227 1.39.137.12 1.39.33.86 ... 97.44.1.207
```

Comment: Try this: `parsed <- read.csv("i.csv", header = F, sep="~", stringsAsFactors = F, colClasses = rep("character", 14))`

Comment: @Narendra thank you! Works like a charm! But why? Why R interpretes `i` as NA? This works as well `df2 <- read.csv2("i.csv", header = F, sep="~", colClasses = rep("character", 14))`

Comment: `read.csv` uses [`type.convert`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/type.convert.html) internally to recycle columns if `colClasses` is not provided with function call. In R 3.2.2 `type.convert("i")` returns `NA` and `typeof(type.convert('i'))` returns `"complex"`. It's a bug. It will be fixed in R 3.3.3. Read more [here](https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/show_bug.cgi?id=16473)

Comment: I've edited my comment. I was commenting on two questions simultaneously and it messed up. Check the edit. And it's R 3.3.0, not 3.3.3.

Comment: @Narendra than you for explanation. Very helpful!

Comment: @Narendra, can you please add this information as an answer?

Comment: @Kirzilla I've added my comment as an answer. If you find this relevant, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of completion, I'm adding my comment as answer.

Almost all the read functions in R (`read.csv`, `read.csv2`, `data`, `read.fwf`, `unzip`, `read.delim`) call `read.table` function internally.

And `read.table` calls `type.convert` to recycle `colClasses` if it weren't provided with the function call.

From `type.convert` at [R docs](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/type.convert.html), it says

> This is principally a helper function for read.table. Given a character vector, it attempts to convert it to logical, integer, numeric or complex, and failing that converts it to factor unless `as.is = TRUE`. The first type that can accept all the non-missing values is chosen.

So, `type.convert` checks if the value is logical, integer, real or complex, in this specific order and if all these options are ruled out, converts value to factor (or character if `as.is=T`).

In R-3.2.1, ([buggy](https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/show_bug.cgi?id=16473)) implementation of `strtoc` and possibly `typeconvert` resulted in conversion of `i` to `NA`. `strtoc` has been corrected in R-3.3.0.

In R-3.3.0, `type.convert('n±ki')` return complex only if k ≠ 1.

From [Changes in R-3.3.0](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/NEWS.html):

> `type.convert("i")` now returns a factor instead of a complex value with zero real part and missing imaginary part.